# Add time to the end of a uploaded file in Uplodify

Tags: php, file-upload

Ok so I have been trying to get this to work and I dont see any errors but my syntax checker swears there is one on line 14. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<?php

// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '***********'; // Relative to the root

 if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$tempFileExploded = explode($tempFile, ".");
//PROBLEM LINE
$tempFile = $tempFileExploded[0] . date('U') . $tempFileExploded[1];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
//mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0777, true);
// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
//$targerfile is the file name
?>
```

The error im getting:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in CODE on line 14
Errors parsing CODE

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem line?  What is the specific syntax error?  Unexpected _____?

Comment: T STRING and no i'm not sure I added in lines 13 and 14.

Comment: Heres the actual error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in CODE on line 14
Errors parsing CODE

Comment: Try swapping the arguments to explode.  It looks like you have them backwards.  The function prototype is [`array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).  But that doesn't look like it should be your syntax error.

Comment: Erm Sorry can you show me an example lol. Sorry i'm newer to php still but i'm getting it!

Comment: Instead of `$tempFileExploded = explode($tempFile, ".");`, It seems that you need `$tempFileExploded = explode(".", $tempFile);`.  It would also help if you added `print_r($tempFileExploded)` after that line (temporarily) to see that it is, in fact, returning an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you explode with dot. you need to extension with dot. so dot is missing in your code

$tempFile = $tempFileExploded[0] . date('U') .".". $tempFileExploded[1];